# maven mac os Lib file for macosx-x86-64 not found in map

Tags: java, macos, maven, appassembler

I copied a jars for a big project from the server to my mac os x 64 bit machine. the jars were working on linux server.

when i run the script that runs the whole come, i got these error:

```
Unable to locate any of the following operational binaries:
  /bla la bla/bin/./wrapper-macosx-universal-64
  /bla bla bla/./wrapper-macosx-universal-32
  /bla bla bla/./wrapper
```

I tried to do `maven clean install` and the clean were **build successfully** though i got these two warnings

and as you see, i put already `macosx-x86-64` (also tried macs-x86-64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given platform does not exist in JSW. You can use the following list of [platforms](http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/usage-daemon-platforms.html):

```
aix-ppc-32
aix-ppc-64
hpux-parisc-64
linux-x86-32
linux-x86-64
linux-ppc-64
macosx-ppc-32
macosx-x86-universal-32
macosx-universal-32
macosx-universal-64
solaris-sparc-32
solaris-sparc-64
solaris-x86-32
windows-x86-32
windows-x86-64
```

Apart from that why are you using an old version of [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/index.html)?

If you need the maxosx-x86-64 platform you need to by a [commercial license of JSW](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp).

Comment: thanks for your answer, i am using a code from my college, what version of appassember do you think is good? plus which platform should I select (from those you listed)? i am working with mac os x yosemite 10.10.1

Comment: when i changed to `macosx-universal-64` i got this error when running the script `wrapper-macosx-universal-64 (Found but not executable.)`  and `Unable to locate any of the following operational binaries wrapper-macosx-universal-3 wrapper` help please

Comment: i added another include tag , so now i have these two: `<includes>
            <include>macosx-universal-64</include>
                                                <include>macosx-universal-32</include>
           </includes>` but i am getting error that found but not executable. help please

Comment: plus i am still using the jars that i downloaded from the server (linux) should I replace any jar? if yes please tell me what jar should I add, i really appreciate the help